# Abnormal CPU usage in power save vs performance mode

Tags: power-management, performance, cpu

CPU usage increases when I change to power save mode, and decreases when I change to performance mode.

What can cause this?

Here is a video to demonstrate:

https://www.reddit.com/user/Faditt/comments/z82fh0/video/

my specs are:

```
           `.:/ossyyyysso/:.               rebyc@rebyc-MS-7D20 
        .:oyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyo:`           ------------------- 
      -oyyyyyyyodMMyyyyyyyysyyyyo-         OS: Kubuntu 22.10 x86_64 
    -syyyyyyyyyydMMyoyyyydmMMyyyyys-       Host: MS-7D20 1.0 
   oyyysdMysyyyydMMMMMMMMMMMMMyyyyyyyo     Kernel: 5.19.0-23-generic 
 `oyyyydMMMMysyysoooooodMMMMyyyyyyyyyo`    Uptime: 2 hours, 26 mins 
 oyyyyyydMMMMyyyyyyyyyyyysdMMysssssyyyo    Packages: 3561 (dpkg), 33 (flatpak), 12 (snap) 
-yyyyyyyydMysyyyyyyyyyyyyyysdMMMMMysyyy-   Shell: zsh 5.9 
oyyyysoodMyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyydMMMMysyyyo   Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1200 
yyysdMMMMMyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyysosyyyyyyyy   DE: Plasma 
yyysdMMMMMyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy   WM: KWin 
oyyyyysosdyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyydMMMMysyyyo   Theme: Arc Dark [Plasma], Breeze [GTK3] 
-yyyyyyyydMysyyyyyyyyyyyyyysdMMMMMysyyy-   Icons: willow-icons-light [Plasma], willow-icons-light [GTK2/3] 
 oyyyyyydMMMysyyyyyyyyyyysdMMyoyyyoyyyo    Terminal: konsole 
 `oyyyydMMMysyyyoooooodMMMMyoyyyyyyyyo     CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11400 (12) @ 4.400GHz 
   oyyysyyoyyyysdMMMMMMMMMMMyyyyyyyyo      GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti 
    -syyyyyyyyydMMMysyyydMMMysyyyys-       Memory: 6146MiB / 15876MiB
```

Comment: The question that you are asking is unclear.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is supposed to happen. Energy use is highly non-linear at turbo CPU frequencies. It takes longer (more CPU usage) to run at lower CPU frequencies, but also less energy.